# Add dot after the figure number in List of Figure (LoF)

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm trying to add a dot after the number of figures in the LoF. I searched for solutions and the only workable one was to add the following to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\newcommand{\autodot}{.}
```

But this code affect my ToC style since it add dots to the sections which I don't want

My code for the ToC:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}

% Rename the contents title
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Content}

%Add dot after the section number
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}%
```

[image: ToC]

My List of Figures:

[image: LoF]

The document class is `article`.

Now how can I add a dot after the figure number without affecting my ToC.

Thanks

Comment: `tocstyle`  and `tocloft` change the appearance of the table of contents and list ofs. Depending on what document class you are using, different packages are *best choice*. A minimal working example would be really really great to reliably answer your question.

Comment: By the way: you do know `\usetocstyle{standard}`. Just in case you are using a standard class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: f505AticleToc]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usetocstyle{standard}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newcommand{\autodot}{.}
\usetocstyle{allwithdot}
\listoffigures
\captionof{figure}{Wombat}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

If you want a dot after the section number in the toc, move the autodot line to the preamble.

Comment: Thank you @Johannes_B for your answer. I want to ask if there is a way to add the dots in the LoF after the figure name?! really thanks

Comment: @F505 Not sure i understand. You asked for *after the figure number*. Where in the screenshot posted is the figure name? Where should this dot be?

Comment: see the output of the LoF in the question. I want it the same in addition to the dot after the number (1.)

Comment: You can do it all in the preamble using `\usetocstyle[lof]{allwithdot}
\settocfeature[lof][1]{entryhook}{\def\autodot{.}}`

Answer (score 4):

`tocstyle` is an alpha package without support. AFAIK it will never become supported, because `tocbasic` will provide several of it's features in another manner. Here a solution using `tocbasic`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[entrynumberformat=\adddot]{tocline}{figure}
\newcommand*{\adddot}[1]{#1\unskip.\hfil}
%\renewcommand*{\listoffigures}{\listoftoc{lof}}% use all of tocbasic (optional)
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\captionof{figure}{wombat}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: using tocbasic]